# Android Exception : unable to find explicit activity

Tags: android

I am new in android and when i run application i got this exception:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class {com.example.activity/com.example.activity.Second};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

so when i want to view an activity from anther activity i got this error.
(I used Lynda to learn android and my sdk version is 24.0.2 , adt is 23.0.6 , and use eclips mars)

main activity java code:

```
package com.example.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Second.class));
        }
    });
}
}
```

second activity java code :

```
package com.example.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Second extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.second);
    }

}
```

manifest XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.activity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".second"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

by the way , when i change my main activity java code like below.everything works fine :

```
public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.second);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: `<activity android:name=".Second"></activity>`, with capital S no with lowercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android is case-sensitive. Replace:

```
<activity android:name=".second"></activity>
```

with:

```
<activity android:name=".Second"></activity>
```

Comment: thanks a lot.but what is the different between this :  startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Second.class)); and this : setContentView(R.layout.second);  both of them work.

Comment: @ehsan: One starts a new activity. The other replaces the UI of an existing activity.

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest

```
    <activity android:name=".Second"></activity>
```

Try this.